# (Ubuntu) How to configure startup application?

Tags: ubuntu, startup, shell-scripting, boot

I'm trying to configure the startup application in Ubuntu. I want to perform the following tasks in sequence when a user login to Ubuntu's desktop:

1. Ensure that the webserver is started automatically.
2. After the webserver has been started, automatically start Firefox web browser and point it to the local webserver.

My question:

1. Where should i put the startup script to perform these startup tasks?
2. How to control Firefox from shell script? e.g. start firefox, and point it to localhost.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you're using the apache httpd daemon.

You can either make it start automatically during boot using the /etc/rc.* folders, or putting /etc/init.d/apache start into your script. I think its apache in ubuntu anyhow, might be called httpd

[This guide](http://www.techsww.com/tutorials/servers/apache_web_http_server/tips_and_tricks/starting_apache_web_server_at_every_reboot_for_debian_ubuntu_linux.php) might help:

start firefox with "firefox localhost" or "firefox 127.0.0.1" in the script